# Cannot open folder because of too many files

Tags: powershell

I wanted to split a file (2.7Go) into 500Mb files using 7z.

Default size unit in 7z is Octet (Who the hell decided this should be default unit).

I've enter 500 thinking default unit was Mb. It created A LOT of files. Now, I cannot open the folder anymore.

I've tried openning a PowerSheel window and type:
Remove-Item Mulan*.7z.*

But it doesn't look like it does anything:
[image]

Any idea how I could proceed to remove those files ?

Thank you

Edit: I've also tried installing rimraf and run "rimraf Mulan*.7z.*" but same result

Edit 2: Rimraf finally did the job after some times :)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this issue using [rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf)

Install nodejs

Run `npm install rimraf -g`

Open command prompt and navigate trough targeted folder

Run `rimraf Mulan*.7z.*`

Go take a coffee or something, takes a while

Done !

Comment: Actually what you have to do, - is to use the same tool. In 7zip(!!!) navigate to the folder in question, select all files (Ctrl+A) then from menu `File->Delete` remove files